# Can't move KinematicBody2D in Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am new to Godot and am trying to move a KinematicBody2D along the x axis, but I am not being able to. Here is the code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D
func _physics_process(delta): 
    var velocity=Vector2(300, 0)
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

I think that this function(_physics_process) is not being called or triggered somehow.

Comment: This is just debugging advice: try adding a `breakpoint` or a `print` call inside of `_physics_process` to see if it is executing. As per why it might not, either the script is not attached to a Node in the scene tree, or some other code elsewhere disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using Godot 2.7. Is that the problem?

In Godot 2 we had `_process` and `_fixed_process`, so the first thing to do is to change `_physics_process` to `_fixed_process`.

And second, it is not enabled by default. So you should call `set_fixed_process(true)` to enable it. Like this:

```
extends KinematicBody2D


func _ready():
    set_fixed_process(true)


func _fixed_process(delta): 
    var velocity=Vector2(300, 0)
    move_and_slide(velocity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the next can help you:

- Make sure the script is attached to the kinematicbody.
- Check the property `sync to physics` of KinematicBody2D in the inspector is disabled.
- Check that you don't have `set_physics_process(false)` inside your script or another one that do this to the kinematic script.

Comment: does not work. I am using Godot 2.7. Is that the problem?

Comment: That may indeed be the problem. Try setting set_physics_process(true) in the _ready function.

Godot 2.x did not activate it physics process automatically, if I remember correctly

Comment: @René Kling
An error message says that set_physics_process is a nonexistent function.

Comment: My bad. See the new answer from Therot. In 2.7 it was called fixed_process